# Startup logic on splash screen loops forever

Tags: flutter, dart, stacked

I am using a splash screen to determine which route to send the user depending on their logged-in state.

My service checks the user state on firebase like so:

```
 Stream<User?> isUserLoggedIn() {
    var user = _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

    return user;
  }
```

My model calls the service and determines the user route based on the response:

```
  User? handleStartUpLogic() {
    print('Run only once and stop magically printing text!');
    _authenticationServices.isUserLoggedIn().listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is signed out!');
        goToSignIn();
      } else {
        print('User is signed in!');
        goToMarket();
      }
    });
  }
```

...and in my View I set on model ready:

```
 return ViewModelBuilder<SplashModel>.reactive(
        onModelReady: (model) => model.handleStartUpLogic(),
        createNewModelOnInsert: false,
        builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: fontColor,
              body: Center(child: Image.asset('assets/fable_Icon.png')),
            ),
```

When I run this code I get this unending looP:

```
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/chatty  (12991): uid=10080(u0_a80) 1.ui identical 10 lines
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/chatty  (12991): uid=10080(u0_a80) 1.ui identical 32 lines
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/zygote  (12991): Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=43KB
I/zygote  (12991): After code cache collection, code=57KB, data=42KB
I/zygote  (12991): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/chatty  (12991): uid=10080(u0_a80) 1.ui identical 156 lines
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/chatty  (12991): uid=10080(u0_a80) 1.ui identical 15 lines
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/chatty  (12991): uid=10080(u0_a80) 1.ui identical 54 lines
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/chatty  (12991): uid=10080(u0_a80) 1.ui identical 21 lines
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
I/flutter (12991): Run only once and stop magically printing text!
```

Will greatly appreciate the help

Comment: Well dont know where `ViewModelBuilder<SplashModel>.reactive` comes from. But a simple answer would be to put that method in the initState of a StatefulWidget.

Comment: It's a state management system called stacked. Very similar to scopedModels.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the build method can be built multiple times, like when you update state. Potentially by getting the model, you are updating the state, which fires the function, which updates the state. You should put it inside an `initState()`.

Comment: I can't use setState. I use a state management system called Stacked. It's great. https://pub.dev/packages/stacked (I hope I can post links)

Comment: Btw, testing with `initState()` returns the same error. There seems to be an issue with the way I am retrieving the user state from firebase?

Comment: I'm really not sure then, sorry. Maybe your user auth listener get's triggered repeatedly, setting off the cycle?